How to get all possible records with highest value in specific column
I have four tables:
Items:



id
name




1
item 1


2
item 2



Item-module:



item_id
module_id




1
1


1
2


1
3



Module:



id
name
type




1
module 1
type_1


2
module 2
type_2


3
module 3
type_2


4
module 4
type_3



Type priority:



id
type
priority




1
type_1
14


2
type_2
20


3
type_3
27



Item could have many modules. Modules have priorities by their type. How could I get all item modules with the highest priority? So the result from this tables should be item with 'module 2' and 'module 3' because item doesn't have 'module 4' and 'module 1' has lower priority than 'module 2' and 'module 3'. So ex of output is
items [
id: 1,
name: item 1,
modules: [
   [
     id: 2,
     name: module 2
   ],
   [
     id: 3,
     name: module 3
   ]
]
]

Table result should look like this:



item_id
item_name
module_id
module_name




1
item 1
2
module 2


1
item 1
3
module 3



But if we add 'module 4' for item than item should have only 'module 4'. 'Module 1' should be in output only if we delete all another modules

please show us your expected result in a table form

Also show us what you've tried yourself to achieve your desired result.

Can you please tell us what RDBMS you are using?

you could add a where clause with a query, something like this
select i.itemid,
       i.itemname,
       m.moduleid,
       m.modulename,
       p.priority
from   items i
  inner join itemmodule im on i.itemid = im.itemid
  inner join module m on im.moduleid = m.moduleid
  inner join priority p on m.type = p.type
where  p.priority = ( select max(p2.priority)
                      from   priority p2
                        inner join module m2 on p2.type = m2.type
                        inner join itemmodule im2 on m2.moduleid = im2.moduleid
                      where    im2.itemid = i.itemid
                    )

This will retrieve all items with joins thru all your tables,
and then filter out those that have not the highest priority
with your data this returns



itemid
itemname
moduleid
modulename
priority




1
item 1
2
module 2
20


1
item 1
3
module 3
20



and if I add module 4 the result is



itemid
itemname
moduleid
modulename
priority




1
item 1
4
module 4
27



see also this dbfiddle
